# google plus sharing on cordova-phonegap

Tags: ios, cordova, google-plus

I am new to phonegap. I wish to implement social sharing in google plus, facebook and twitter.

I have successfully implemented facebook and twitter sharing following the following link:

https://github.com/EddyVerbruggen/SocialSharing-PhoneGap-Plugin

The link says that we can use this plugin for google + too. But I didn't find any syntax for google + sharing in the link.

How do i implement google plus sharing in phonegap app?

Answer (score 2):

It's only supported on Android at the moment.

Use shareVia('com.google.android.apps.plus', ...)

Comment: ok , so how do I share via google+ in iOS in phonegap app? Is there any other plugin for that?

Comment: any update on sharing image via google + in iOS cordova /ionic?